# Array loop not showing all the data?

Tags: javascript

Hello i need some help as my array is not showing everything display

The picture show there 3 array data but however one is display only as this is the on i written to display for 1 i have included a for loop but it seems not working here my code for it

i have JSON.phase to it call responses

This is my array response

```
[{"Recyclable": "unknown recyclable name"},{"Recyclable": "some recyclable name"},{"Recyclable": "another recyclable"}]
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/01QpV.png)

This is my code

```js
const responses = JSON.parse(user.CdsRecyclables)


document.getElementById('name').value = "" + responses[0]["Recyclable"]

for (let i = 0; i < responses.length; i++) {
  responses[i]["Recyclable"] + "<br>";
}
```

```html
<div class="container-body ">
  <fieldset class="Field">
    <label id="symbol">-><input id="name" disabled></label>
  </fieldset>
</div>
```

Comment: Please update your code in the question to remove extra variable and keep only whatever is necessaary so the code snippet works

Comment: hi the code snippt would not work as i didnt include my ajax in it

Comment: `responses[i]["Recyclable"] + "<br>";` creates a string, but then throws it away because you don't do anything with it...?

Comment: @TheNoob - Stack Snippets are for **runnable** [mre]s demonstrating the problem. You can use a stand-in for ajax, [details here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/).

Comment: The inner part of the loop has no effect. You probably want to update `document.getElementById('name').value` but actually you don't.

Comment: do i have to include the  document.getElementById('name').value = "" to it ?

Comment: Please try: `for (let i = 0; i < responses.length; i++) { document.getElementById('name').value += "" +  responses[i]["Recyclable"] + "<br>"; }` And remove `document.getElementById('name').value = "" + responses[0]["Recyclable"]`

Comment: im not exactly sure what you're trying to do, could you explain what you expect to happen?

Comment: Display all the array into the input and with a br 
there only 3 array

Comment: oh thanks is working now but the br tag somehow is displaying along with the array

Comment: You are setting some input's value, it can't be HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code and let me know if this solves your problem

```
let responses = [{"Recyclable": "unknown recyclable name"},{"Recyclable": "some recyclable name"},{"Recyclable": "another recyclable"}]

let field = document.querySelector(".Field");
let str = "";

for (let i = 0; i < responses.length; i++) {

    response = "" + responses[i]["Recyclable"]
    str += `
        <label id="symbol">-><input id="name" disabled value="${response}"></label><br/>
    `;
    field.innerHTML = str;

    console.log(response)
    
}
```

Comment: Insane it work as what i wanted

Comment: Since is working nicely i have a question can we css this field let say when it hit 30 row it goes to the right side ?

Comment: check the array length, if it is less than 30, leave it like this:
`<label id="symbol">-><input id="name" disabled value="${response}"></label>`

if the length exceeds 30, add some class that arranges it in the way you want:
`<label id="symbol">-><input id="name" class="moreThanThirty" disabled value="${response}"></label>`